# Should I use # or #!

Tags: ajax, seo

I am doing some ajax page with jQuery, can you tell me which are the differences (especially for SEO point of view) between pages like:

- page.html#option1
- page.html#!option1

Edit: mh maybe the second options is google-friendly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `#!` if you want your site crawlable by Google. More information is found on their [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) guide. So yes, the second version is more SEO-friendly. Another post worth reading is Googles propsal for [making ajax pages crawlable](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html).

However, for a users point of view, there's no difference.

Just a tip, [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) is a great library for working with this. It allows you to define routes using hash fragments.

Comment: Just to clarify, adding #! in itself will not make the website more crawlable or google-freindly. You need to implement the underlying features to make it work, as explained in the links from @alexn.